# Limit Zbar to QR code only in Python

Tags: python, qr-code, zbar

I'm using Zbar with it's Processor option in Python. I've been trying to figure out how to limit the symbology to QR-code only, but have only found answers for C as it follows:

```
scanner = new ImageScanner();
scanner.setConfig(Symbol.QRCODE, Config.ENABLE, 1);
```

I understand that the original code is written for C but is there anyway to do it in Python? Python isn't my main language and it's a bit difficult for me to understand what the arguments are in this case for `processor.parse_config()` (which I have currently set to 'enable'):

From https://github.com/npinchot/zbar/blob/master/processor.c

```
static PyObject*
processor_parse_config (zbarProcessor *self,
                    PyObject *args,
                    PyObject *kwds)
{
    const char *cfg = NULL;
    static char *kwlist[] = { "config", NULL };
    if(!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "s", kwlist, &cfg))
        return(NULL);

    if(zbar_processor_parse_config(self->zproc, cfg)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "invalid configuration setting: %s",
                 cfg);
        return(NULL);
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

I don't even understand why 'enable' is a valid argument.

Comment: Look in [zbarmodule.c](https://github.com/npinchot/zbar/blob/master/zbarmodule.c) perhaps you have to disable the other barcode types e.g. EAN8. They are at the bottom of the file, line 185 onwards.

Comment: Nice find! But I still can't figure out how to input it, since vim shows parse_config as `processor.parse_config(param)` it doesn't say much about the structure of the input argument. Besides, 'disable' isn't even listed in zbarmodule.c, but it works to disable all symbologies.

Comment: I don't have it installed but you might find some help from an interactive python console. Use `import your_lib` then type `help(your_lib)`. This should give you some basic information and you might even be able to get more detailed help using `help(your_lib.your_function)`

Comment: The help page doesn't  directly show the answer since it's wrapped C in Python, but this surely will be of use in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time to figure this out since there's no documentation and the config format is counter-intuitive, IMO, but here you go:

```
proc.parse_config('disable')
proc.parse_config('qrcode.enable')
```

The first line, `disable`, disables **all** scanners.
The second line enables the qrcode scanner.